# Maximum sum of values of the list to the power of their indices, while only adjacent swap allowed and one element can be swapped only once

Tags: python, list

Maximize the sum of the values of list to the power indices
Example of the sum :

```
  [3,1,4] : 3**1 + 1**2 + 4**3 = 68
```

**Conditions**:

1. Only adjacent swap allowed
2. One element if swapped once cannot be swapped again

**Test case 1**:

```
 [4,3,5,2,1]
```

Ans: `653`

Explanation:
If we swap one element only once, the final array would be
`3,4,2,5,1`. Sum would be `3+16+8+625+1=653`

**Test case 2**:

```
[5,4,1,2,3]
```

Ans: `329`

Exp: rearranged array `[5,1,4,2,3]`

Sum `329`

I tried to go by logic find maximum element and find maximum adjacent position possible of it,
But 2nd case will fail

Comment: Firstly, you have not shown us any code so there is nothing any one can do to tell you where you may be going wrong.  Second, you have not explicitly asked a question and it is unclear as to what exactly you'd like help with.

Comment: most likely a Homework question

Comment: Maybe Puzzling would be more appropriate forum? https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the answer to 2nd case?

Comment: @LoukasPap He showed the answer `329` and the correct rearranged list. The problem is his logic won't produce those results because he will swap the `5`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't know if by swapping the max element ahead, you are actually preventing a more advantagious move. Notice that the numbers with the larger indices are more relevant than large numbers, since e.g. `3**7-3**6 >>> 8**2-8**1`. One possible approach (memoized recursion):

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def maxpowsum(nums, i=0):
    # base case: end of list
    if i >= len(nums):
        return 0, ()

    # option 1: do not swap current index, move 1 ahead for recursive call
    rec_sum1, rec_tpl1 = maxpowsum(nums, i+1)
    o1 = nums[i]**(i+1) + rec_sum1  

    # option 2: swap current with next, move 2 ahead for recursive call
    if i < len(nums)-1 and nums[i] > nums[i+1]:
        recsum2, rectpl2 = maxpowsum(nums, i+2)
        o2 = nums[i]**(i+2) + nums[i+1]**(i+1) + recsum2
        if o2 > o1:
            return o2, (nums[i+1], nums[i], *rectpl2)

    return o1, (nums[i], *rectpl1)

>>> maxpowsum((5,4,1,2,3))  # use tuple for hashability
(329, (5, 1, 4, 2, 3))
>>> maxpowsum((4,3,5,2,1))
(653, (3, 4, 2, 5, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient approach would be to split the list in the middle and recurse on both sides once with a swap and once without.  Then take the largest combined result (original vs swapped):

```
def swapPower(L,k=1):
    if len(L)<2 : return sum(L)**k
    m = len(L)//2
    original = swapPower(L[:m],k)+swapPower(L[m:],k+m)
    left,a,b,*right  = L[:m-1],*L[m-1:]
    i,j = k+m-1,k+m
    swapped = swapPower(left,k) + b**i+a**j + swapPower(right,j+1)
    return max(original,swapped)
```

output:

```
A = [4,3,5,2,1]
print(swapPower(A)) # 653

B = [5,4,1,2,3]
print(swapPower(B)) # 329

C = [5,4,1,2,3]*7   # 35 items
print(swapPower(C)) # 23295183763258016796437
```

*Because of the splitting in two, the function will not hit Python's recursion depth limit (it only recurses logN levels)*

```
D = [4,3,5,2,1]*200 # 1000 items
print(swapPower(D))
# 186712471691585083024585776393209260886902097945684223875983182577618220025563307149175801676112578292105677592559003531218357452251031461908936800776085154981154343058524796073226289213412382033757957709922630401817404087323018070648459332227033355073735451874568803795776266550183131628558172311024662689704140174395008439472856476478991838336876760397817802307134821747905344772323295889876978108869859827329030004684359637828503865410315406460860112760196511250086566330818761975000364292937277206441471905596876447312526800472498547004923771964951849551145143376093066117365045967787036535898715645077337961140670668909970306805674238090732272060626709482270280063357547206934718885379556760200
```